# Results from matrix multiplication differs on Python and MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab

I have a problem that I cannot understand and it drives me really crazy because I can't find a solution.

I am doing some matrix multiplication on MATLAB and Python. Imagine that I have two matrixes X and W and I want to multiply them. 
In Python I use numpy and I go like this:
`np.dot(X, W)`

In MATLAB I do: `X*W`

The result on Python is this one:

```
[[ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -1.79812377e-01   1.26046711e-02  -3.62915515e-01  -2.28314197e-01
    9.41395740e-02   1.95587346e-01   4.00916792e-02   4.61162174e-01
   -1.54852385e-01   2.07742254e-01]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]
 [ -7.25949823e-04  -9.78931123e-04  -2.20816949e-05  -2.52954078e-03
   -2.53120361e-03  -3.53331962e-03  -3.62886737e-03  -4.73257530e-03
   -4.44088094e-05  -4.29659134e-03]]
```

Result on MATLAB:

```
-0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

0.4886    0.4726    0.7100    0.9864    0.6025    0.5887    0.9668    0.4671    0.2921    0.9398

-0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043

   -0.0007   -0.0010   -0.0000   -0.0025   -0.0025   -0.0035   -0.0036   -0.0047   -0.0000   -0.0043
```

I would like to know why the second row is different. 
The `X` and `W` matrices are below:

PYTHON:

```
W = np.array([[ 0.16157533,0.17941953,0.11275408,0.4501205,     
0.38326338,0.49979055, 0.56796654,0.61752605,0.05109819,0.63738453],     
[0.51000276,0.35098523,0.81868132,0.92687111,0.38791804,0.29996999,     
0.70714705,0.00453668,0.34100865,0.55859484],     
[0.31635177,0.99422952,0.81529534,0.42029186,0.58907765,0.20727667,     
0.75791727,0.07188677,0.27872427,0.92982283]])

X 
[[ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [  7.38717964e-01  -6.55268545e-01   1.10692571e-01]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]
 [ -7.67758224e-03   9.73418978e-04   5.72517607e-05]]
```

MATLAB

```
W = [0.16157533 0.17941953 0.11275408 0.4501205 0.38326338 0.49979055 0.56796654 0.61752605 0.05109819 0.63738453;0.51000276 0.35098523 0.81868132 0.92687111 0.38791804 0.29996999 0.70714705 0.00453668 0.34100865 0.55859484; 0.31635177 0.99422952 0.81529534 0.42029186 0.58907765 0.20727667 0.75791727 0.07188677 0.27872427 0.92982283];

Xf = [-7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; 7.38717964e-01 6.55268545e-01 1.10692571e-01; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05; -7.67758224e-03 9.73418978e-04 5.72517607e-05];
```

Comment: maybe you could reduce your matrices size, which would create a better [mcve]

Comment: Most probably both the results are correct. It is just how you are using output format size to display your result in MATLAB. Check Command Window output display format.

Comment: As xhienne points out, this looks like a simple typographical error (a difference in the sign of element (2, 2) for each of the X matrices). As such, it's off-topic.

Comment: Another pointer. Before asking your question. Maybe it is better to test a small example, with a small matrix to see if the concept works. Because if it works of one then, most probably it should work for other too. 

Because usually MATLAB or numpy have designed their libraries to be general to all types of valid matrix multiplication.

Comment: Yes, @gnovice, that was the error. Thank you!

Comment: Voting to close due to a typo.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, the seventh value of `X` is `-6.55268545e-01` (negative).

In Matlab, the seventh value of `xf` is `6.55268545e-01` (positive).

There may be other discrepancies, I stopped searching at the first I found.

Comment: It was just that! Thank you so much, I didn't notice it. Now the two matrixes are the same.